# fnmatch() returning false with pure wildcard

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
echo "matching: ".$params['perm']." against: "; var_dump($perm);
if (fnmatch($params['perm'], $perm)) { $x=true; }
$this->code = 200;
return $x;
```

For which I am asking if `$perm` contains the start of `$params['perm']` or is `*`

In this case my output is:

```
matching: acl.adduser against: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "*"
}
{"code":200,"data":false}
```

Shouldn't it return true since `*` is the permission I have, and this allows me to also own `acl.adduser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$perm` is supposed to be a string, while in your example it is an array. `fnmatch` would not work correctly in this case, and you should have also seen a PHP warning about this.

Also, the order of the arguments appears to be reversed. This test works as expected:

```
var_dump(fnmatch('*', 'acl.adduser'));
```